# Efficient sampling to render an expression made up of random variables

Tags: sampling, importance-sampling

Let's say I have a few random variables, like

$
x_1 \sim N(0, 1)\\
x_2 \sim N(2, 1)\\
x_3 \sim U(0, 2)
$

I would now like to render the following distribution, an algebraic expression made up of these variables, e.g.

$
y = x_1 * x_2 + x_3
$

To do this, I can draw random triplets of samples for $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$ to evaluate $y$, collect many such values for $y$, and then draw a distribution via a kernel density estimate of some kind.

Unfortunately, the result looks quite noisy until I've drawn an enormous number of samples. Is there a better strategy than drawing these samples randomly? Assume that all parameters are known, and that I can automatically differentiate $y$ with respect to $x_i$.

Comment: If you draw iid triplets $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ the variability of $Y$ is correctly represented.

Comment: One possible strategy is to work out mathematically what the distribution of $y$ must be so you can avoid sampling altogether.  Otherwise, nothing you do is going to reduce the variability in any sampling scheme.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks, fixed.

Comment: You can easily derive that $\mathbb E[Y]=1$ and $\text{var}(Y)=16/3$...

Comment: To put it differently, if I can only draw 100 triplets, would I get a better chance at faithfully approximating $Y$ if I followed some non-random sampling strategy (farthest-point, quasi-random, etc.)? If so, can you point me to literature that gives a overview over various strategies, computational cost, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by faithfully?! If you draw 100 triplets and turn them into $Y$'s, this is 100% faithful with a direct pseudo-random simulation of $Y$. As put by @whuber, if you wish for a mathematical representation of $Y$, it is feasible to find the density of $Y$.

Comment: By faithfully I mean I'd like the shape of the 100-triplet KDE to match the 100000-triplet KDE as closely as possible, minimizing the risk of too many triplets randomly landing in an unrepresentative clump in some corner of $X$-space. Unfortunately, the expressions are complicated enough that I can't work out $Y$ analytically/symbolically.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:**
First, using a standard notation for normal distributions, you have
$X_1 \equiv 1,$ so that $X_1X_2 \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu=3,\sigma=1).$
Then $E(Y) = E(X_1X_2 + X_3) = 3 + 1 = 4.$ and
$Var(Y) = Var(X_1X_2 + X_3) = 1 + 1/3 = 4/3.$

You are not going to derive the density function of
$Y$ by using simulation. If you choose independent large samples, say of size $n=10^6$ from the distributions of $X_i, i = 1,2,3,$ then a kernel
density estimator of $Y$ will give you a good idea of the density
function of $Y.$ You are right about needing a large number $n,$ but
simulation should not be difficult.

You could use the resulting KDE to check your analytical
solution for the density of $Y,$ but not as a substitute for the analytical derivation itself.

```
set.seed(411)
x1 = rnorm(10^6, 1, 0)
x2 = rnorm(10^6, 3, 1)
x3 = runif(10^6, 0, 2)
y = x1*x2 + x3

summary(y);  sd(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -1.746   3.213   4.002   4.000   4.788   9.342 
[1] 1.154607   # aprx SD(Y) = sqrt(4/3) = 1.1547
sqrt(4/3)
[1] 1.154701   # exact SD(Y)
```

There are many variations on KDEs. Below, I used the default KDE in R.

```
hist(y, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
 lines(density(y), col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]

But be careful: $Y$ does *not have exactly a normal* distribution with
$\mu = 4, \sigma = \sqrt{4/3}.$

```
ks.test(y, pnorm, 4, sqrt(4/3))

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  y
D = 0.0026177, p-value = 2.234e-06
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

**Addendum** per edit of question and Comment by @Xi.an. Now there is no longer any danger of mistaking the distribution of $Y$ for normal.

```
set.seed(412)
x1 = rnorm(10^6, 0, 1)  # change
x2 = rnorm(10^6, 3, 1)
x3 = runif(10^6, 0, 2)
y = x1*x2 + x3
hist(y, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
 lines(density(y), col="orange", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: The typo was corrected: it is a $N(0,1)$ not a $N(1,0)$ distribution. Hence centred at $1$ and with variance $16/3$, much more peaked than a Normal distribution.

Comment: See addendum incorporating correction.